# Why doesn't this OpenCV code do anything?

Tags: c++, opencv

I've been trying to use OpenCV with C++ but even though my code compiles (Visual Studio 2010 ), it doesn't ever do anything:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "cvaux.h"
#include "cvwimage.h"
#include "cxcore.h"
#include "cxmisc.h"
#include "ml.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;



int main()

{

    namedWindow("yolo", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    waitKey(1);
    cout << "Why won't this show up?" << endl;
```

}

It compiles OK, without errors but the program doesn't do anything - when I open it in console, it doesn't return the 'Why won't this show up?" text - there is nothing returned.

Regardless of which tutorial piece of code I am trying to use, it never works and never does anything.

What is going on?

Best regards

**EDIT:** When I set the wait time to 0 (forever) it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The window does get created, however, because you have the waitKey function set to 1 millisecond it only exists for a very short period of time. Try using:

```
waitKey(0);
```

Comment: Still nothing, the cout line isn't ever processed ( the program doesn't return any text in console ). Could this be somehow caused by trouble with linking or header files? But then why is it compiled?

Comment: I use visual studio 2010

Comment: Just to cover all the grounds, not to offend, but are you looking at the debug output or the actual command line? I ask, because this should work, I tested it with my system and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

waitKey(1); is the culprit. the minimum time is 1 millis (that#s what you got here)

either make it :

```
waitKey(0); // forever
```

or increase the time to something sensible

```
waitKey(5000); // 5 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be,

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

cv::namedWindow("test_1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
cvWaitKey();
std::cout << "This will work because I just tested it." << endl;
```

I use CMake to link the libraries. The CMake code is,

```
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( myProject ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Could you share a list of your include commands? I think I must have done something wrong with linking.

Comment: I have just added the includes and also the CMake code to link the libraries.